# Symmetric matrix problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$A$ is a symmetric matrix and has a eigenvalue $\lambda$ of order $m$.

Why $\lambda$ has $m$ independent eigenvectors?

I want to prove $A$ is diagonalizable by proving it has $n$ independent eigenvectors. And I know that different eigenvalue has independent eigenvectors but I don't have an idea about the same eigenvalues.

Comment: Considering that $A$ is always diagonalizable, you can express exactly the eigenvectors of $A$ in the diagonalized coordinate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hereby introduce you the Schur decomposition, which is a simple decomposition can be used to prove the diagonalization of symmetric matrix very quickly.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition

After decomposing $A$ into the upper triangular form, you can prove that it is indeed the diagonal form.

Comment: sure.
schur decomposition is one of the most effective decomposition I know in linear algebra

Comment: Sorry to trouble you again but I still want to know if there is a way to prove “there are m linear independent eigenvectors that belong to a multiple root $\lambda$ with order m ” directly. I have read many books but can not find a directly proof.some use the congruent transform on symmetric matrix some use schur decomposition.thanks.

Comment: I think that's very direct proof :D, I'm sorry but in my limited knowledge I don't know a simpler way to prove that fact